# Covering Shapes with as Few Rectangle as Possible

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm for finding the fewest rectangles to cover a set of rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles)

I need some help figuring out an algorithm.  I have a shape laid out on a grid as shown below.

[Shape on Grid http://www.benfillmore.com/shape.png](http://www.benfillmore.com/shape.png)

The goal is combine the squares into larger rectangles like so:

[Larger Rectangles http://www.benfillmore.com/boxes.png](http://www.benfillmore.com/boxes.png)

I'm trying to cover every square in the shape with as few rectangles as possible.  It's okay if the rectangles overlap each other:

[Overlap http://www.benfillmore.com/overlap.png](http://www.benfillmore.com/overlap.png)

I'm not looking for full solutions, just ideas, or someone pointing me in the right direction.  I've implemented a couple ideas, but they don't even come close to optimal.  I'm not worried about processing time, that's only done once at shape creation.  I just need as few rectangles as possible.

Thanks a million

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks a million, that should work great.  At first glance it looks perfect.  Now I need to spend a few minutes wrapping my head around it.