# Combining many rectangles into fewer rectangles

Tags: c#, java, compression, collision-detection

I want to compress many non-overlapping rectangles into larger rectangles When they are adjacent.

Pseudo-code for my current algorithm:

```
do
   compress horizontally using sweep and prune
   compress horizontal output vertically using sweep and prune
while (this output is small than previous output)
```

Here's a [link to sweep and prune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune).

This is working well, but I want to know if there are approaches which result in fewer rectangles output. I figure there's more sophisticated than what I'm doing now.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the new criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it sounds like your problem is that you have small gaps between the rectangles preventing them from being collected together into a single piece.  If you have access to the source code for  the sweep and prune method, you can add a buffer to the "overlap" test, but I think it would be more optimal to consider using an R-Tree.  This will index the rectangular spaces without messing with limits on gaps etc.

[R-Tree Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

Here is a relevant paper by Sellis et. al. describing the R+ tree:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=50ECCC47148D9121A4B39EC1220D9FB2?doi=10.1.1.45.3272&rep=rep1&type=pdf

here is a C# implementation of an R-Tree

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cspatialindexrt/

[Edit - After Comment 1]

So let me see if I can capture the current problem.

- Rectangles are joined in passes of horizontal/vertical adjacency tests.
- Rectangles are only joined if the adjacent boundary for both is equal.
- The intermediate result of any join must also form a valid rectangle.
- The result is non-optimal because the sequence of joining.

I think you're actually looking for the minimum dissection into rectangles of a rectilinear polygon.  The first step would be to join ALL the touching rectangles together, regardless of whether they form a rectangle or not.  I think you are getting caught up in problems with the intermediate stages of each step in the process also needing to be complete rectangle deconstructions, leading to a sub-optimal result.  If you merge them together into a single rectilinear polygon, you can use graph theory mechanisms.

[image: Minimum Dissection into Rectangles of a Rectilinear Polygon]

You can check out [Graph-Theoretic Solutions
to Computational Geometry Problems](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3916v1.pdf) by [David Eppstein](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/)

Or investigate [Algorithm for finding the fewest rectangles to cover a set of rectangles without overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles) by [Gareth Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68063/gareth-rees)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Rtree looks interesting but i dont think it will work for me. Here if there is a gap the rectangles cannot be combined. The output should have the same area as the input and cover exactly the same ground.

Comment: The second link sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Once I've had time to read it I'll reply or accept. I appreciate your time here.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, I can't thank you enough. Hopefully the solution is not out of my depth. Complex stuff.