# Complex Polygons to Composite Rectangles ArcGIS

Tags: polygon, arcgis, image-segmentation

I'd like to break down some polygons I have into composite rectangles in an automated process. I want to establish the largest sized rectangle that could fit inside the polygon and then leave the other components to be whatever size is required.

I would've put up a simple example but don't have '10 reputation'.

It's a simple problem but I have searched through stackoverflow and couldn't find anything relevant. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

James

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105837/get-largest-inscribed-rectangle-of-a-concave-polygon

Comment: Thanks for the redirection, although this link is the most useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles