# c# summarise Blocks in a Grid like structure

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-engine

i am searching for an algorithm that can find the the biggest Areas in a Grid.

if i have something like this:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/14v1lbo.png]

Red Blocks = Blocks with Collision

i have to check 28 collision Objekts.

I need an algorithm that can find this:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/sy3spi.png]

now i only have to check 5 Objekts.

Is there an easy c# algorithm for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the absolute minimum number of rectangles, then I would suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6634668/2144669) to you. Since you want easy, though, here's my suggestion, which is 2-competitive with the minimum. First, by scanning the rows one by one, find the minimum exact cover with rectangles only one row high.

```
00000000
1      2
3  44  5
6  77  8
99999999
```

Now for each pair of adjacent rows in turn, try to merge their rectangles. Assuming that they are sorted by horizontal position, then the loop looks like a sorted merge.

```
00000000
--------
1      2
```

No merges possible.

```
1      2
--------
3  44  5
```

Merge `1, 3` and `2, 5`.

```
1      2
1  44  2
--------
6  77  8
```

Merge `1, 6` and `4, 7` and `2, 8`.

```
1      2
1  44  2
1  44  2
--------
99999999
```

No merges possible. The final result is the following.

```
00000000
1      2
1  44  2
1  44  2
99999999
```

Answer (score -2):

here is a solution for Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public  class CollisionTileMerger:MonoBehaviour{

    ArrayList rects = new ArrayList();

    public int[,] rowCheck(int[,]array)
    {
        int y = array.GetLength(0);
        int x = array.Length /y ;

        int count = 1;
        ArrayList rec = new ArrayList ();

        for(int i=0; i< y ;i++){

            for(int j=0; j< x ;j++)
            {
                if(array[i,j] == -1)
                {
                    array[i,j] = count;
                    rec.Add(i);
                    rec.Add(j);
                }
                else
                {   
                    if(rec.Count>0)
                    {
                        rects.Add (rec);
                        rec = new ArrayList();
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(rec.Count>0)
            {
                rects.Add (rec);
                rec = new ArrayList();
                count++;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    public int[,] Merger(int[,]array)
    {
        int y = array.GetLength(0);
        int x = array.Length /y ;
        int[,] coppy = (int[,])array.Clone ();

        for (int i=0; i< y-1; i++) 
        {
        int row = i;
        for (int j=0; j< x; j++) 
        {
            if(coppy[row,j]>0&&coppy[row+1,j]>0)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    coppy[row+1,j] = coppy[row,j];
                }
                else
                {
                    if((coppy[row,j-1]>0&&coppy[row+1,j-1]>0)||(coppy[row,j-1]==0&&coppy[row+1,j-1]==0))
                    {
                        coppy[row+1,j] = coppy[row,j];

                            if(j==x-1)
                            {
                                //letzte Zeile
                                //speichern
                                array = (int[,])coppy.Clone ();

                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //zurücksetzen
                        coppy = (int[,])array.Clone ();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(coppy[row,j]==0&&coppy[row+1,j]==0)
            {
                //speichern
                array = (int[,])coppy.Clone ();
            }
            else
            {
                //zurücksetzen
                coppy = (int[,])array.Clone ();
            }

        }

        }
        //speichern
        array = (int[,])coppy.Clone ();


        return array;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        int[,] a  = new int[,] {
                    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0,-1},
                    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}};

        displayArray (Merger(rowCheck (a)));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void displayArray(int[,]array)
    {
        int y = array.GetLength(0);
        int x = array.Length /y ;
        string row="";
        for (int i = 0; i< y; i++) 
        {

            for(int j = 0; j<x;j++)
            {
                row+= array[i,j]+" ";

            }
            row+= "\r\n";
        }
        Debug.Log(row);
        /*foreach( int a in array )
        {

            Debug.Log( array.GetLength(0) );
            Debug.Log( array.Length );

        }*/


    }


}
```