# Combine Adjacent 2D Points/Ranges

Tags: java, algorithm, aspose

I'm using [Aspose Cells for Java](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/cells).

I'm operating on an Excel spreadsheet. I'd like to iterate over every cell, and if two cells are touching and share the same style ID, combine them into a separate single range for later processing. As more cells are iterated over, existing ranges could grow.

A range consists of `startRow`, `endRow`, `startCol`, and `endCol` properties. If all four properties are equal, it represents a single cell.

For example, I'd expect `{(1,1),(1,1)}` and `{(2,2),(1,1)}` to combine into `{(1,2),(1,1)}`. Meanwhile `{(1,1),(1,1)}` and `{(2,2),(2,2)}` would not combine because they are diagonal, not adjacent.

I think I could use a variation of an [interval tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/) for this, but I'd have to adapt it for 2D intervals. However, in this case I don't care if two ranges overlap; if two ranges overlap, they are overlapping rectangles, in which case combining them would do nothing for minimizing the number of total ranges.

[Here is a crudely drawn idea of the intput/output I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13yiN.png).

My best guess is that I'd have to iterate outward from every cell and compare the style IDs. As I go over and down from the current cell, check the rest of the cells in that range for the same ID and create new ranges based on that.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check this question: [Algorithm for finding the fewest rectangles to cover a set of rectangles without overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles-without).

Comment: Your question is about algorithm and not about Aspose.Cells features.We are afraid, you will have to write your own algorithm or search from internet. ---- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose