# Given an array of cuboids, how do I consolidate them into the minimum number of cuboids possible to represent the same overall shape/volume?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, rectangles

Say I have 10 cubes in a line, I'd want to represent that as 1 cuboid with a size of 10 units along whatever axis they're lined up on. However, if I add another cube next to the first to form a little "L" shape, then it'd take at least 2 cuboids to represent the shape.

If I had some complex arrangements of connected cubes/cuboids, how could I calculate the minimum number of cuboids necessary to represent their shape/volume?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles-without This seems to be a 2D solution, I would look into extending it into 3D